# How to set multiple headers for column in header of QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qheaderview

I am having a QTableWidget and let's say it has 4 columns with headers as Failed DIPS, Failed Outputs, Extra DIPS, Extra Outputs. Now my requirement is that I should categorize the columns i.e to say that I need to add two more headings such as Failed and Undefined. And Under the Failed - Failed DIPS and Failed outputs should come and under Undefined Extra DIPS and Extra Outputs should come. That is to say that I need two additional headers in addition to existing normal headers. And these additional headers will group the existing headers to make more sense. Please can anyone guide me how to do it.

Something like this

[image]

Comment: @eyllanesc will it work for non-model based tables like QTableWidget?

Comment: yes, because are not you modifying the model, but the headerview

Comment: @eyllanesc ok, thank you :)